# MS Excel: IF and AND nested

Tags: excel

Can someone help with simple excel look up function: How can I pull assigned doctors from the table?

```
        All other cities
        and countries       Chicago   Boston    Atlanta   California   Dallas

General     Lee               John

Pediatrics  Greg

Dermatology Greg                       Peter      Lee

Optholmol   Greg

Radiology   Mary

Surgery     Greg                                            Mary         Greg
```

For ex., Dermatology and Boston should return Peter, but Dermatology from any other city should return Greg

Comment: I tried to format it right, but I was a bit confused because you said Dermatology and Boston should return "Peter" but _all_ other cities return Greg? did you forget about "Lee" or is Peter's last name Lee?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, you are correct the look up should return Peter if it is Dermatology and Boston, should return Lee if Dermatology and Atlanta, Dermatology and any other city should return Greg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Formulaic answer (no macros or VBA):

If you have a table set up like this:

[image]

And on another sheet or range you desire this as your output:

[image]

You can use this formula, assuming that the input is in A2 and B2, and the table is on Sheet2 in the range of A2:G8:

```
=IF(
    IFERROR(
        INDEX(Sheet2!A2:G8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A8,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A2:G2,0)),0
    )=0,
    INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A8)),
    INDEX(Sheet2!A2:G8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A8,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A2:G2,0))
 )
```

To explain:

1. The formula: `INDEX(Sheet2!A2:G8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A8,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A2:G2,0))=0` will test to see if a Doctor exists for the given pair of lookup values.

   This formula is getting the row and column value from the array specified:

   ```
   IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A2:G8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A8,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A2:G2,0)),0)=0
                  ^^ array ^^    ^^ match the row ^^    ^^ match the column ^^     ^^ True if no doctor is found
   ```
2. If no doctor exists then we can return a lookup from `B2:B8` which is the "All other cities and countries list": `INDEX(Sheet2!B2:B8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A8))`
3. If one does exist we can just output that doctor: `INDEX(Sheet2!A2:G8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A2:A8,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A2:G2,0))`

Comment: Thanks, almost there.  But, output for Surgery and New York or Dermatology and Newark comes out as N/A instead of Greg.

Comment: Works for everything except for output with General, for ex., General and New York or General and Chicago.

Comment: Found the error, had a space after city.  Thank you very much for your help. Greatly appreciate it.